# Want to disable outline when clicking on element with link (can't get it working with Firefox)

Tags: html, css

So I want to disable the outline when clicking on a link, but I still want users to be able to tab through all links with a keyboard.  Therefore, this fix should work

```
a:active {
    outline: none; }
```

It works for all browsers except for Firefox. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are content with requiring your keyboard users to have JavaScript activated (I know, not perfect) you could give each link an outlined class `onfocus`, and remove it `onblur`.

For a more thorough approach, check out this [**blog entry**](http://stamatiskritikos.com/2010/01/03/remove-dotted-outline-vs-accessibility/) that discusses removing the outline from a accessibility 
perspective.

Comment: That blog entry is broke.  By the way

Answer (score 0):

a {outline:none;}

hope this helps